# Don't allow a specific use of characters

Tags: c#, character, directory, specifications

I bumped into a problem, i hope someone can help me out :)
I got a TextBox, and i want to limit users, so that they can't write multiple `\` one after another.
I'm using it for folders. For instance: `C\temp\test\`
Now I want to prevent input like: `C\temp\test\\\`

I've tried searching around for this problem, but I couldn't find anything like this, so I hope it's possible :)

I don't really have any code to show, but here's the code for my TextBox:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^C^D^A^E^H^S^T^]");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(textBox1.Text);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Character niet toegestaan!");
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            clsOpslagMedium objOpslag;  // definieert type object 
            objOpslag = new clsOpslagMedium();  // creert opject in memory
            objOpslag.DriveLetterString = textBox1.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception variableEx1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Foutmelding: " + variableEx1.Message);
        }
    }
```

I hope I provided enough information :)

Comment: The quality control procedure is likely trying to save us from a question with no code to show initial effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - TextBox Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404947/c-sharp-textbox-validation)

Comment: OnKeyUp() check the text

Comment: Do you want to make it impossible for someone to write it from the beginning, or do you wish validate it once it has been changed?

Comment: "just typing some extra text here because the question body does not meet quality standards.. lol" Just downvoting here because the question does not meet quality standards.. lol

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textbox don't allow typing " \ " 2 times after each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193770/textbox-dont-allow-typing-2-times-after-each-other)

Comment: @JohnKraft No, it's actually the other way around. The question you're linking to is actually an exact duplicate of this one.

Comment: He posted twice his question.

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox contains `\\`, it is invalid:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Contains(@"\\"))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error!");
}
```

Comment: @X.L.Ant I almost, ***almost*** downvoted this answer for putting a wrong answer. `textBox1.Text.Contains("\\")` will always hold true, when you write paths into `textBox1`. The original answer was correct.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `textBox1.Text.Contains(@"\\")` or `textBox1.Text.Contains("\\\\"))`? edit; you fixed it and I am a slow typer.

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work. i hope you can help me out som further. i tried doing                 if (textBox2.Text.Contains("\\, \\, \\\\, \\\\, \\\\,  \\\\\\, \\\\\\\\"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }

Comment: @Ricje20 you know, '\\\' contains '\\' as do '\\\\' and so on... no need to test anything else than '\\'. Just try with what's provided.

Comment: @Ricje20 Your `Contains` will only return true, if your TextBox contains that string, for instance: `"hello \\, \\, \\\\, \\\\, \\\\, \\\\\\, \\\\\\\\ world"` would work, but not `"hello \\ world"` or `"hello \\\\ world"`