# Textbox don't allow typing " \ " 2 times after each other

Tags: c#, textbox, character

I bumped into a problem, i hope someone can help me out :)
i got a textbox, and i want to limit users so that it isn't allowed to have two \ after each other.
i'm using it for folders. for example: C\temp\test\
now i want to make it not possible to type C\temp\test\\

i've tried searching some around for this problem but i couldn't find anyting like this. so i hope it's possible :)

heres a code of my textbox how it is now

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^C^D^A^E^H^S^T^]");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(textBox1.Text);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Character niet toegestaan!");
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            clsOpslagMedium objOpslag;  // definieert type object 
            objOpslag = new clsOpslagMedium();  // creert opject in memory
            objOpslag.DriveLetterString = textBox1.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception variableEx1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Foutmelding: " + variableEx1.Message);
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can give some examples and that I provided enough information :)

Comment: why don't you just use `textBox1.Text.Contains(@"\\")` to test if you got 2 \\next each other ?

Comment: Please do not post twice the exact same question.

Comment: Sorry pierre, i bumped into a problem and posted it tiwce, i didn't mean to do this

Comment: This is a bad idea. First, paths are allowed to contain two backslashes, eg `\\myserver\myshare\mydirectory\myfile.txt`. Second, if you want users to browse folders, **create a folder browser control**, not a text box.  Third, you're going to have to write code that handles malformed paths regardless; there are lots more ways to malform a path than just two backslashes, so don't bother restricting the input. Allow all the input and then give a good error message if its bad. Fifth, catching all exceptions is a bad programming practice; catch only the exceptions you intend to handle.

Comment: Sixth, eliminating double backslashes as people type leads to bad situations. For example, suppose I type `c:\d\e.txt` and then I realize whoops, I meant to write `c:\f\e.txt`, so I put the cursor after the `d`, hit backspace, the double-backslash disappears and now I end up with either `c:\fe.txt` or `c:f\e.txt`, neither of which is what I want. You're trying to be too clever here, and producing a user experience that is frustrating and unpredictable.

Comment: @EricLippert I think he just poorly worded what he wanted in the original question, he left a comment in keyboardP's answer which makes me think he really just wants to use a `ErrorProvider` and a check on the control's `Validating` event (and I added a answer explaining how to do do).

Comment: It would make things a Ton easier if i could post a screenshot >.< but i don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [a textreplace isn't working in my case. i need an error shown up when a user leaves the box when he types more then one \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193770/textbox-dont-allow-typing-2-times-after-each-other/17194418#comment24901507_17193847)

If this is what you really want you need to use a [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx). Add one to your form then add the following code to the texbox's `Validating` event and be sure that `CausesValidation` is true for the textbox

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"\\\\+"))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        errorProvider1.SetError(textbox1, @"\\ Is not allowed");
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(textbox1, null);
    }
}
```

This will make a `!` show up next to the text box if they type wrong and force them to correct it when they attempt to leave the text box.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to simply replace the string.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the current cursor position so we can reset it 
    int start = textBox1.SelectionStart;

    textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\\\\+", @"\");

    //make sure the cursor does reset to the beginning
    textBox1.Select(start, 0);
}
```

The extra code surrounding the replace ensures the cursor doesn't reset to the start of the textbox (which happens when you set the `Text` property).

Comment: Would this work if someone pasted "c:\temp\\\" ?

Comment: Yes, it will replace any number of sequential backslashes with one instance.

Comment: he could test in in a loop `while (textBox1.Text.Contains(@"\\")){textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\\+", @"\");}`

Comment: Oh, you edited your answer to @"\\+" :)

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - Just in time :D

Comment: a textreplace isn't working in my case. i need an error shown up when a user leaves the box when he types more then one \

Comment: @Ricje20 - you said "don't allow typing" and "make it not possible to type". So now you are changing the requirements...

Comment: @Ricje20 Then you'll want `if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"\\{2,}")) // error`

Comment: @Ricje20 - Your question stated you wanted to prevent them from typing in two slashes. Nolonar's solution will work if you just want to perform a check.

Comment: I think your patten is matching unnecessary matches, `@"\\\\+"` would be better. You need doubled up because the regex engine needs them escaped too, just like you would need to if you did not include `@` (if you did not include `@` your pattern would need to be `\\\\\\\\+`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Thanks for the optimization tip, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all `\`-sequences (`\\`,`\\\`,`\\\\`, ...) and replace that on `\`. You can use regex for search sequences

Sample:

```
      string test=@"c:\\\adas\\dasda\\\\\\\ergreg\\gwege";
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\*");


       MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(test);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Value!=string.Empty)
                test = ReplaceFirst(test, match.Value, @"\");
        }
```

Comment: can you give a little example? ~thanks for the answer!